# Navigation Drawer over action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-actionbaractivity

I m using navigation drawer and action bar tabs in my application but navigation drawer is coming below action bar tabs.I wants to show navigation drawer over action bar tab layout.Any suggestion how to do? i dont want to use actionbarsherlock lib.

Comment: Interesting.  Usually the complaint that it is coming up over the ActionBars is the problem.  This is the typical normal behavior that you are requesting.  I had found it to do this by default.

Comment: @JaySnayder No i am talking about actionbar tab layout not action bar.Navigation drawer is coming below action bar tab layout.I want to show it below action bar but over action bar tablayout.